# Show video preview / thumbnail of video using QML

Tags: qt, qml, multimedia

Since Qt5.15 there is a **flushMode** property in [Video](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-video.html#flushMode-prop). If set to **VideoOutput.FirstFrame** video shows first frame if playback has reached end of video. How can I show first video frame without starting it. Like a thumbnail or preview regularly seen in OS icon view. I would like to avoid storing additional images next to the videos for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in a [Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37301?focusedCommentId=431229&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-431229) you could do it as follows:

```
    Video {
        autoPlay: true

        onStatusChanged: {
            if (status == MediaPlayer.Buffered)
            {
                pause()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't show first frame after end of video but it shows a thumbnail like image before playing it.

Comment: @PjToopmuch Is it different from what you asked for?

Comment: @dimril Doing this, I have to play the video once before the thumbnail shows up. Is this normal?

Comment: @pooya13 That's not how I see it. Literally, the playback should initiate by "autoPlay: true" but as soon as it's buffered it should be paused. If it's not paused then probably the onStatusChanged callback isn't triggered or the condition is faulty. Debug those to see exactly which case is it.

Comment: For some reason your condition didn't work for me but `Component.onCompleted: pause()` did. Anyways thanks for your help.